# Mysql results problem

Tags: mysql

I'm making a website for my school and I need help with Mysql result. I need to know when is the gym available for use, ex : its busy from 2009-09-23 until 2009-09-30 and available all other dates, now I wrote a query but it aint workin.

```
   SELECT gym_name from gym, logs WHERE gym.gym_id = logs.logs_id 
    AND (gym.date_busy_from < '2009-09-23' 
    OR gym.date_busy_from > '2009-09-23' 
    AND gym.date_busy_till > '2009-09-30')
```

Can someone help me I'm stuck for hours, and I can't breach the wall. tnx

Comment: this query looks incomplete, don't you at least need to prefix it with "select "? Also, your join syntax is the deprecated variety. You should change to the join syntax that uses the "join" keyword.

Comment: Please post table sql and some sample data

Comment: You should tag this with school work

Comment: Just a note, it's easier to read if you use UPPERCASE for all the MySQL keywords/functions as well as starting each action on a new line

Answer (score 1):

Yours. What does the OR condition do or what are you trying to do with it?

```
SELECT gym_name from gym, logs 
WHERE gym.gym_id = logs.logs_id 
AND (gym.date_busy_from < '2009-09-23' 
OR gym.date_busy_from > '2009-09-23'
AND gym.date_busy_till > '2009-09-30')
```

Try

```
SELECT gym_name 
FROM gym, logs
WHERE gym.gym_id = logs.logs_id
AND gym.date_busy_from < CURDATE()
AND gym.date_busy_till > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Or

```
SELECT gym_name 
FROM gym, logs
WHERE gym.gym_id = logs.logs_id
AND gym.date_busy_from > CURDATE()
AND gym.date_busy_till < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

is the gym.date_busy_from stored in varchar format, or Date format?  That would matter on your comparison.  I don't see your parenthesis closed after the first AND statement.

Comment: Never mind, I see the closed parenthesis.  My idea would be the comparison.  Personally I would wrap all the where statements in there own sets of parenthesis.

Comment: its DATE format, I edited post 2 times maybe you didn't see it . Parenthesis is there, maybe I need to add another somewhere ?